# Error with photo upload batch request + multi users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-batch-request

I have application with publish_stream that I can post status updates on my users walls, now I want to post photos, after searching I read about batchrequest and made my code like that

```
<?php 
require_once('./includes/config.php');
require_once('./includes/skins.php');
require_once('./includes/functions.php');
require_once('./includes/facebook.php');
 $app_id = "$appid";
 $app_secret = "$appsec"; 

$sql=mysql_query("select `f_id`, `facebook_access_token` from `users` ");
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$f_id=$rows['f_id'];
$facebook_access_token=$rows['facebook_access_token'];   
$batched_request = '[{"method":"POST", "relative_url":"'.$f_id.'/photos",' 
    . ' "body" : "message=لو بتحب جاهين و رباعياته اشترك معانا فى التطبيق و هننشرلك على بروفايلك اجمد رباعيات صلاح جاهين http://2lshmaker.uni.me/jahin/", "attached_files":"file1"}}]';

$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . "?batch="
    . Urlencode($batched_request) . "&". $facebook_access_token 
    . "&method=post";
}  
 echo ' <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.$post_url.'" 
       method="POST">';
 echo 'Please choose 2 files:';
 echo '<input name="file1" type="file">';
 echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" />';
 echo '</form>';
?>
```

But it gives me that error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Top level access token or app id not specified for batch request.",
      "type": "GraphBatchException"
   }
}
```

I don't know what I got that despite already having publish_stream and valid access_token

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a top level access token, even if you're including an access token for each individual request in the batch

Read the section marked 'Specifying different access tokens for different operations' in the batch API documentation

> All the above examples specify a single access token as a top level
>   parameter. The Batch API is flexible and allows individual requests to
>   specify their own access tokens as a query string or form post
>   parameter. In that case the top level access token is considered a
>   fallback token and is used if an individual request has not explicitly
>   specified an access token.
>
> This may be useful when you want to query the API using several users'
>   different access tokens, or if some of your calls need to be made
>   using an Application access token.
>
> If none of the individual requests specify an access token to be used,
>   you must include an access token as a top level parameter and this
>   will be used for all requests.

Assuming `$facebook_access_token=$rows['facebook_access_token'];` returns a list of access tokens these need to be appended *within* each call in the batch, so `$batched_request` should have an equal number of calls to match the number of access tokens you are supplying. In addition to that you need a top level access token if any of the token you supply fail, so most likely it will be the application access token as the fallback.

Specific to your code, you aren't even defining the top level access token parameter correctly, it should be

`$post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . "?batch="
    . Urlencode($batched_request) . "&access_token=". $facebook_access_token 
    . "&method=post";`

**"&access_token=". $facebook_access_token**
`------^MISSING^`

That is it must be in the form of field and value. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: i really can understand what is written in the error , the question is what is  top level access token ad how can i make the code work successfully

Comment: After @phwd added the docs, it's STILL NOT HELPFUL. I've read those docs, but they don't provide a working example nor an explanation of what is wrong with the above code. That's the point. The docs aren't helpful because they are vague and do not provide an example. Not a helpful answer.

Comment: Please don't mention me if you don't have anything to say other than it's not helpful. It's a two way street. You have to give detail of your problem as well to get detail. This is indeed the solution to the problem for the OP because he pushed the call in PHP as `"&". $facebook_access_token` which will most like equate to `ADXXXXXXAccessToken` instead of `access_token=ADXXXXXXAccessToken` notice the missing `access_token` portion. So the error is indeed correct he didn't specify it properly. Also please don't type in CAPS it's an annoying way to get attention to people who are trying to help